# How can I detect with reflection in Scala if a contructor parameter is implicit?

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose I have a

```
class A(msg: String)(using ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long)
```

and I want to tell that it has 2 implicit parameters using reflection.

I tried something like

```
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
println(m.classSymbol(getClass).primaryConstructor.info.paramLists)
```

but this recognizes only one parameter list.

Also tried isImplicit

```
println(m.classSymbol(getClass).primaryConstructor.info.paramLists.head.map(_.asTerm.isImplicit))
```

and it did not work, returned false for all.

I'm using Scala 3.3

Comment: Did you try with a single list of implicit parameters? So that you can know if the issue you're facing is with the implicit parameters of with the multiple lists of parameters.

Comment: Is it `import scala.reflect.runtime`? Because Scala 3 does not developed its own runtime reflection AFAIK, and what you see comes from Scala 2.13 standard library, so it might NOT understand Scala 3 super well.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok It's `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror`
I highlighted that this is Scala 3 because I used the `using` keyword

Comment: @GaëlJ Tried, same results. It always unifies the parameter lists and does not recognize which are the implicit parameters

Comment: Yes, I saw you used Scala 3 syntax, but Scala 3 uses 2.13's standard library (plus a few extra things) and this is where `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a difference between code compiled with 2.13 and 3.

When you compile this code in 2.13:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class B(msg: String)(implicit ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long)

locally {
  val b = classOf[B]
  val m = runtimeMirror(b.getClassLoader)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor.info)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor.info.paramLists)
}
```

you get this result:

```
constructor B
(msg: String)(implicit ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long): Playground.B
List(List(value msg), List(value ctx1, value ctx2))
```

See [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/biNInAqWRdy22B9jYIQkLQ/13).

Meanwhile in Scala 3:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.*

class A(msg: String)(using ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long)

locally {
  val a = classOf[A]
  val m = runtimeMirror(a.getClassLoader)
  println(m.classSymbol(a).primaryConstructor)
  println(m.classSymbol(a).primaryConstructor.info)
  println(m.classSymbol(a).primaryConstructor.info.paramLists)
}

class B(msg: String)(implicit ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long)

locally {
  val b = classOf[B]
  val m = runtimeMirror(b.getClassLoader)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor.info)
  println(m.classSymbol(b).primaryConstructor.info.paramLists)
}
```

prints:

```
constructor A
(msg: String, ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long): Playground.A
List(List(value msg, value ctx1, value ctx2))
constructor B
(msg: String, ctx1: Int, ctx2: Long): Playground.B
List(List(value msg, value ctx1, value ctx2))
```

See [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/biNInAqWRdy22B9jYIQkLQ/9).

I believe the reason is that:

- Scala 2.13 and Scala 3 has slightly different bytecode (and Scala 3 also uses Tasty files)
- Scala 2.13 and Scala 3 **compilers** know how to read each other's bytecodes (Scala 2.13 requires `-Ytasty-reader` flag though)
- Scala Reflection Library is a library which was not only compiled for 2.13 but also written so that it would read Scala's metadata from bytecode and use this knowledge to provide information that vanilla Java reflection isn't aware of
- but 2.13's library was not adjusted to read Scala 3's metadata in bytecode

So when you compile Scala 3 code adding a dependency on Scala 2.13 library, compiler can read and use this library but the library cannot read the extra bytecode attributes/Tasty that Scala 3 provided.

As a result you see what JVM sees which is uncurried method.

Comment: So basically, a Scala 3 version of scala-reflect would solve my problem?

Comment: There is no Scala 3 version of scala-reflect, and that's the problem.

Comment: Understood; I will create a workaround till then.